# Proper way to loop over the length of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops

After quite a bit of debugging today, to my dismay i found that:

```
for (i in 1:0) {
     print(i)
}
```

Actually prints 1 and 0 respectively in R. The problem came up when writing

```
for (i in 1:nrow(myframe) {
     fn(i)
}
```

Which i had intended to not execute at all if nrow(myframe)==0. Is the proper correction just:

```
if (nrow(myvect) != 0) {
    for (i in 1:nrow(myframe) {
        fn(i)
    }
}
```

Or is there a more proper way to do what I wanted in R?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `seq_along` instead:

```
vec <- numeric() 
length(vec)
#[1] 0

for(i in seq_along(vec)) print(i)   # doesn't print anything

vec <- 1:5

for(i in seq_along(vec)) print(i)
#[1] 1
#[1] 2
#[1] 3
#[1] 4
#[1] 5
```

#### Edit after OP update

```
df <- data.frame(a = numeric(), b = numeric())
> df
#[1] a b
#<0 rows> (or row.names with length 0)

for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))) print(i)    # doesn't print anything

df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 5:7)

for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))) print(i)
#[1] 1
#[1] 2
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the edit, see the counterpart function `seq_len(NROW(myframe))`. This usage is exactly why you don't use `1:N` in a `for()` loop, incase whatever value ends up replacing `N` is 0 or negative.

An alternative (which just hides the loop) is to do `apply(myframe, 1, FUN = foo)` where `foo` is a function containing the things you want to do to each row of `myframe` and will probably just be cut and paste from the body of the loop.

Answer (score 4):

For vectors there is `seq_along`, for DataFrames you may use `seq_len`

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(the.table)){
    do.stuff()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Clearly all previous answers do the job.

I like to have something like this:

```
rows_along <- function(df) seq(nrow(df))
```

and then

```
for(i in rows_along(df)) # do stuff
```

Totally idiosyncratic answer, it is just a wrapper.
But I think it is more readable/intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most proper way in R is to use an `apply` function. More often than not, there's an `apply` function that does that.  And more often than not, you don't need a sequence.

Here's an example that applies `diff` to each column, or each row.

```
> d <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 6:10)
```

over the columns,

```
> lapply(d, diff)
$x
[1] 1 1 1 1

$y
[1] 1 1 1 1
```

across the rows,

```
> apply(d, 1, diff)
[1] 5 5 5 5 5
```

over the columns again, returning a matrix

```
> sapply(d, diff)
     x y
[1,] 1 1
[2,] 1 1
[3,] 1 1
[4,] 1 1
```

See this link for [a most excellent explanation about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega/7141669#7141669) `apply`

Comment: "I think the most proper way in R is to use an apply function" -- with all due respect, I don't think this is good advice. It's OK for there to be two or more ways to do something, but the "wrong way" can't be the most obvious and usually workable way, with the "right way" trailing somewhere behind it; that's just messing with people's heads. For what it's worth.